# JSHint says "Argument types do not match parameters" for jQuery(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

It's all in the title.

It happens with *jQuery(document)* as well.

I don't understand what is wrong in the code.

Here's the excerpt:

```
var checkboxes = jQuery('.js-selected-items', self.$el);
checkboxes.each(
    function (i) {
        if (!jQuery(this).is(':disabled')) {
            jQuery(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
);
...
```

That warning is shown for all occurrences of *jQuery(this)*.

The code works, of course, but I'd like to get rid of all JSHint warnings.

Comment: Using `.each()` in your case is unnecessary. The same can be done by this: `select_all.prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, but this doesn't really address the issue. I've updated the question with a slightly different snippet.

Comment: What type is `jQuery` expecting?

Comment: Well, I also wonder what type is expecting. "this" is, I suppose, the element. Following jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/each/) "this" is suppose to be the current element in the loop. And jQuery(this) is simply supposed to work. But JSHint still doesn't like it.

Comment: @AndreaSciamanna: this is why "code quality" tools like JSHint and JSLint need to be taken with a grain of salt --- They always seem to complain about things that _don't actually_ matter in real life. Code quality tools are often someone's opinion about how a language should be written, as opposed to a tool pointing out just syntax and logic errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a flag for JSHint to allow the use of `this` outside of a constructor function:

```
checkboxes.each(function() {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    jQuery(this)...
});
```

From the [JSHint docs for the `validthis` configuration option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis):

> This option (`validthis`) suppresses warnings about possible strict violations when the code is running in strict mode and you use this in a non-constructor function. You should use this option—in a function scope only—when you are positive that your use of this is valid in the strict mode (for example, if you call your function using Function.call).
>
> **Note:** This option can be used only inside of a function scope. JSHint will fail with an error if you will try to set this option globally.

Under the hood, `jQuery#each` invokes your callback using `Function#call` passing the current element in the loop as the first argument to that function, making the `validthis` flag for JSHint OK to use in this situation.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as more related to JSHint, even though I also like the one proposed by Fwolf.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of function of `$.each()` is:

```
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
```

So use `element` instead of `this` will satisfy JSHint, or PHPStorm inspection in my case.

```
checkboxes.each(function (i, elm) {
    if (!$(elm).is(':disabled')) {
        $(elm).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: In `jQuery.each`. the `this` variable points to the "current element" in the loop, so `jQuery(this)` should work just fine.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Both code works, and use too many of `this` may be confused sometime :-) And if several `each()` is used, several jshint comment looks not so pretty.